# Want to de-link my business Facebook page from my personal email

Tags: facebook-pages

I have a personal Facebook page and a business Facebook page. I could not create my business FB page with my business email address, because it seems FB does not like "info@" email addresses. I have created a different business email address which is acceptable to FB. However, I now need to de-link my personal email account with that business page, so that I can log in as myself when I want to use FB personally and I (or a manager) can log in using a different email address to manage the business page. If I want my managers to be able to update the page right now, they'd have to log into my FB account, which is obviously not ideal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you could just add other admins (e.g. the people with whom you work) to the business page so that they would be able to administrate and act as the page without being in your personal account. There are different kinds of [Admin Roles](https://www.facebook.com/help/323502271070625/) you can use to control who is able to do what for the page etc. To do this you:

> 1. At the top of your Page, click **Edit Page**
> 2. Select **Manage Admin Roles**
> 3. Enter the name or email address of the person you'd like to add
> 4. Click **Manager**  below the name to choose the [admin role](https://www.facebook.com/help/289207354498410)
> 5. Click **Save** and enter your password to confirm changes

If you want to use your other email address you will have to set up either a personal or business account on facebook with that email address. Once you have registered that email address to facebook you will be able to add that new account as an admin to the page.

Once you have set up the new account as a top-level administrator if you wish to remove your personal account as an admin you can do that as well (from [Transferring a Facebook Page to a New Administrator](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/transferring-facebook-new-administrator-30348.html)):

> Return to the "**Edit Page**" link and click "**Manage Admins**" from the list
>   on the left. Click the "**Remove**" button next to your own name. Click
>   "**Save Changes**" and enter your password. You are no longer an admin of
>   this page and it has been transferred to the new admin.